# using TextField in Accordion Summary Lock my input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, material-ui, react-hook-form

I use textField in material ui accordion and I cant type any word in it. I use lots of way and no different.This is react hook form.

```
<Grid>
  <TextField size="small" variant='outlined' defaultValue={item.title} {...register('title')} 
  />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :-)
Is there a `value` property without an `onChange` handle in our returning `register` object? If that's the case, it will aways be what's inside `value`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html for more information.

Comment: tnx. its not about value. I search it and i realize it is about accordion in material ui.